# How does Sap Life work on a Dhampir?

Tags: spells, feats, pathfinder-2e

The [Sap Life](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=273) feat provides you HP when you damage a living creature with Harm. There is just one requirement, you need to be a living creature.

If you have the [Dhampir](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=23) heritage, you are "**half living** and half undead", and are "healed by negative effects *as if* you were undead".

So if you cast 1st level Harm, spending 3 actions, dealing 5 damage (to a living creature in range) in an emanation, how much are you healed? I expect it to be 6 HP, 5 from Harm itself, and 1 from Sap Life.

Comment: That's a tough question, good spot. Interested to see others' thoughts, I can't quite make up my mind on it. For context for others, the ability to become full undead is (presumably) coming in the upcoming Book of the Dead. So it's not like the only case in which the PC can be even somewhat undead is via Dhampir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Same as Any Living Creature

A dhampir would be healed by Sap Life because they are a living creature (despite their closeness to undeath), and because Sap Life is not a **positive** healing effect.

Here's from the ancestry [description](https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=23):

> Despite being living creatures, dhampirs respond to positive and negative energy as if they were undead

And from the [negative healing](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=42) ability dhampir's have:

> A creature with negative healing draws health from negative energy rather than positive energy. It is damaged by positive damage and is not healed by positive healing effects. It does not take negative damage, and it is healed by negative effects that heal undead.

Sap Life doesn't have the positive trait that many other healing abilities like [*breath of life*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=29) and [*lay on hands*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=395) do, so a dhampir's negative healing wouldn't prevent it from working and they would be healed just as any other living creature would.

A 1st-level *harm* with a roll of 5 would heal the dhampir for 6 points as you suggested, as long as any living creature also took damage from the spell.

Answer (score 8):

## Sap Life Is Triggered

The *[harm](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=146)* spell heals a dhampir, so you heal 5 points, from your example.

With one or more ***other*** living creatures affected by the spell, if any of them takes damage, then you gain the benefits of Sap Life, healing 1 more point.

> When you cast a *harm* spell and damage at least one living creature, you regain Hit Points equal to the spell level of your harm spell.

If you are the only target of *harm*, then no damage is dealt to you, and Sap Life doesn't trigger.

Comment: I thought "_dealing 5 damage in an emanation_" shows clearly enough that there is a living creature in range, but apparently not. Edited.